# Autowiring beans with similar annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a scenario where there are multiple classes implementing same interface. But few of them are annotated with one annotation and rest with other annotation. Now I want to autowire a list of classes which are annotated with a particular type of annotation. Is it possible to achieve it merely by using annotations only?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Fruit{...}

@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Vegetable {...}

public interface Food {...}

@Fruit
@Component
public class Banana implements Food{...}

@Vegetable
@Component
public class Tomato implements Food{...}

public class Test{

@Autowired
@Fruit
List<Food> fruitList; // Getting instance of both Banana and Tomatao
}
```

Here, fruitList get autowired with the instances of both Tomato and Banana rather than getting Banana only; which is not exactly what I have been looking for. Please could anyone help me to understand what I have been missing here?

I was expecting an annotation based autowiring here but it's picking up all implementations of Food Interface.

Comment: no, why don't you get them to all implement a base interface

Comment: @EssexBoy, Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: @EssexBoy is suggesting that you replace your `@Fruit` and `@Vegetable` annotations with interfaces, instead. For example: `public class Banana implements Food, Fruit { ... }` (or just `Fruit` and have `Fruit` extend `Food`). Then you can autowire collections by-type using the most specific interface, such as `List<Fruit>`. To apply the annotation-based behavior that you specifically asked for you would likely need to implement custom autowiring behavior on top of `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces to create a type hierarchy

```
public interface Food {
}

public interface Vegetable extends Food {
}

public interface Fruit extends Food {
}

public class Banana implements Fruit {
}

public class Tomato implements Vegetable {
}
```

Then you can control things:

```
@Autowired
List<Food> foods; // Getting instance of both Banana and Tomatao

@Autowired
List<Fruit> fruits; // Getting instance of only Banana

@Autowired
List<Banana> bananas; // Getting instance of only Banana

@Autowired
List<Vegetable> vegetables; // Getting instance of only Tomato

@Autowired
List<Tomato> tomatos; // Getting instance of only Tomato
```

Comment: It will work this way but is it possible to achieve it merely using annotations only?

Comment: @Jaraws no Autowire is by type/interface.